# Alternative methods to handle OpenLDAP's new config syntax slapd.d/cn=config?

Tags: openldap

I for one feel that configuring OpenLDAP with LDIFs instead of basic configuration files is a major step in the wrong direction.

Does anyone have some tools/techniques to more easily manage OpenLDAP that don't require LDAP to be working 100%?

Answer (score 4):

For configuration changes, I nearly never submit them via LDIF files and `ldapmodify` calls but use a GUI like Apache Directory studio, which makes this a lot less cumbersome.

However, if you somehow manage to destroy your config in such a way that you can't connect via LDAP anymore, you can manually edit the `cn=config` tree in an editor, as this is just a collection of LDIF files in (usually) `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/`. Just make sure `slapd` is stopped, edit the files, restart `slapd` and you should be back in (but be sure to make a backup beforehand).

Comment: If you manually edit the ldifs configuration in /etc/openldap/slapd.d, to prevent noisy warnings from some ldap-related utility, like slapcat, you have also to [manually update the checksum on the header of the ldif](http://serverfault.com/questions/499856/is-there-any-bad-thing-happens-if-i-change-etc-ldap-slapd-d-cn-config-ldif-manu).

Comment: +1 for Apache Directory Studio, [this is a good beginner article on how to edit `cn=config` using it.](http://gos.si/blog/installing-openldap-on-debian-squeeze-with-olc)