# openLDAP is not importing ldif to "cn=config"

Tags: openldap

I'm having issues setting up an admin group for an openLDAP.

I have just moved to olcconfig and have set up the following ldif:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: {3}to dn.subtree="dc=mysite,dc=com"
 by group(s)/groupOfNames/member="cn=admin,ou=group,dc=mysite,dc=com" manage
```

I try to add this via `sudo ldapadd -D "cn=diradmin,dc=mysite,dc=com" -f admin.ldif -W -x` where diradmin is the root dn.  When I do this, I get:

```
modifying entry "olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config"
ldap_modify: Insufficient access (50)
```

I've read a few different tutorials but cannot see why this is occuring.  Could anyone assist in likely causes (and even point out a good tutorial!).

Thanks.

------ Edit -----

I have now tried: `sudo ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f admin.ldif`

The following was my error:

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config"
ldap_modify: Insufficient access (50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to update the `olcAccess` attributes for your `dc=mysite,dc=com` you actually need permissions on the `cn=config` database.

The root DN you're trying to use will only work for updating objects in the `dc=mysite,dc=com` database, it doesn't/shouldn't have permission on the `cn=config` database.

I don't know how you generated your configuration, but it looks like you need to add at least something like `olcAccess: to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" manage by * none` on the `olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config` object. That would then allow you to use the `EXTERNAL` auth mentioned in the other answer to apply your original LDIF change.

If you don't have any ACL's configured that allow you to update the `cn=config` database then you can try the accepted answer in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/499856/is-there-any-bad-thing-happens-if-i-change-etc-ldap-slapd-d-cn-config-ldif-manu) to edit the database files that are usually under `/etc/ldap/slapd.d` or `/etc/openldap/slapd.d`.

Comment: When moving to olc, I did declare `database config`, `rootdn="cn=admin,cn=config" and rootpw {SSHA}EncryptedPassword` in the slapd.conf, so that dn should be able to modify `cn=config` I had thought.  Is this not correct?

Comment: I think that should work. Have you tried to apply your LDIF file using that DN?

Comment: I obviously misunderstood the context.  This is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert by any kind, but I think it might be an issue with you setup your config to begin with, which would need more config data to be troubleshooted, but if you want to apply an LDIF you can bypass the bind-dn by using the EXTERNAL auth trick:

`ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f <filename>`

And then read this ol' thread to see if it helps you solve the issue: https://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201306/msg00220.html

Comment: Sorry, I did try this previously and got the same, which is why I enforced the root dn.  Updated the question, thanks.